# Currency List with possible symbols - iPhone Application Development

Tags: uitableview, ios4, core-data, nsnumberformatter

In one of my iPhone application I need user to set currency from settings Tab. It's a core data application. I can put all currencies in a table.

Now what's the best way to apply selected currency to numbers/decimals? e.g. If selected currency is GBP then a £ is shown and if a currency is selected which does not have a symbol then three letter abbreviation is shown. I know a little bit about NSLocale. What are all possible localization values for currencies?

Can anybody also point me to where to get mainly supported currencies and symbols list?

That would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about NSLocale but for a table of the symbols, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol#List_of_presently-circulating_currency_signs